# Unable to add same product more than once in CodeIgniter cart

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, cart

I am developing a shopping cart using codigniter  2.1.4. My issue is that I am unable to add same product more than one time in cart. But I can update the quantity in cart. 
So my requirement is that when cart the item for second time quantity should be increment to 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Cart.php replace the following code

```
unset($this->_cart_contents[$rowid]);
```

with this

```
if(isset($this->_cart_contents[$rowid]))
{
$this->_cart_contents[$rowid]['qty']++;
return $rowid;
 }

unset($this->_cart_contents[$rowid]);
```